# Powershell - shortened the directory prompt, but how to save the change?

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell in Windows 10. To change the prompt from:

```
PS C:\Users\b.HQ\Desktop\tsdev\my_folder> 
PS my_folder> tsc
```

I used the following command in Powershell:

```
function prompt {'PS ' + $(Get-Location | Split-Path -Leaf) + ">"}
```

But, each time I restart Powershell, I have to reenter this. **Is there any way to persist this change?**

P.S. I know nothing about the config of Powershell, and I have looked for a solution, but apart from the prompt I am using, I did not see a way of saving it.

Comment: `PS C:\> help about_Profiles`

Answer (score 9):

Run `powershell` as **administrator**, then run the following:

`Test-Path $Profile`

if it returns `false` then no you don’t have a profile file yet, so create it:

`New-Item –Path $Profile –Type File –Force`

(this will create profile file, or will overwrite the existing one)

Then, edit your profile file:

`notepad $Profile`

put your function in the file and save.

Answer (score 1):

I created this neat prompt to that shows the drive and last folder.

For you example it would render as

```
PS C:\Users\b.HQ\Desktop\tsdev\my_folder>
```

as

```
PS C:\...\my_folder>
```

The prompt function is:

```
function prompt {"PS " + (get-location).drive.name+":\...\"+ $( ( get-item $pwd ).Name ) +">"}
```